# Spark and Python use custom file format/generator as input for RDD

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark

I would like to ask about input possibilities in Spark. I can see from http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html, that I can use `sc.textFile()` for reading the text files to RDD, but I would like to do some preprocessing, before the distribution to RDD will happen, for example my file might be in JSON format eg. `{id:123, text:"...", value:6}` and I would like to use only certain fields of the JSON for further processing.

My idea was if there is possible somehow to use Python generator as an input to the SparkContext?

Or if there is some more natural way in Spark how to process custom, not text only files by Spark?

**EDIT:**

It seems that accepted answer should work, but it has moved me to my more practical following question [Spark and Python trying to parse wikipedia using gensim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202978/spark-and-python-trying-to-parse-wikipedia-using-gensim)

Comment: You can always load the JSON into an RDD, and then do your processing on the RDD to filter in only the data you need. The advantage of doing it this way is that this "pre-processing"-type work becomes parallelized across your Spark cluster. Can you give an example of what kind of processing you'd want to do first?

Comment: By preprocessing I mostly mean that I would like to only select for example fields text1, text2 from either JSON or XML and then I can do something like split it by whitespace and save it as text file.
I don't see any natural way how to parse JSON RDD. Now I can think only of going through the JSON or XML as a sc.textFile() file and whenever seeing the desired key, then use the following string. Was that what did you mean?

Comment: Yeah, I think I have a feeling for what you're trying to do. Comment on my answer if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way to do this is probably to load the text file as-is and do your processing to select desired fields on the resulting RDD. This parallelizes that work across the cluster and will scale more efficiently than doing any preprocessing on a single machine.

For JSON (or even XML), I don't think you need a custom input format. Since PySpark executes within a Python environment, you can use functions regularly available to you in Python to deserialize the JSON and extract the fields you want.

For example:

```
import json

raw = sc.textFile("/path/to/file.json")
deserialized = raw.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
desired_fields = deserialized.map(lambda x: x['key1'])
```

`desired_fields` is now an RDD of all the values under `key1` in the original JSON file.

You can use this pattern to extract a combination of fields, split them by whitespace, or whatever.

```
desired_fields = deserialized.map(lambda x: (x['key1'] + x['key2']).split(' '))
```

And if this gets too complicated, you can replace the `lambda` with a regular Python function that does all the preprocessing you want and just call `deserialized.map(my_preprocessing_func)`.

Comment: I'm trying to implement and run this example, so I'll let you know if that worked for me as soon as I make it work. 

I'm now just quiet surprised that this should actually work, because for example my JSON might be bigger than RAM memory across all the machines, so I'd expect that there will be loaded only part of it at once and thus json.loads(x) would get just part of it and it will not be able to parse it properly?

Comment: Actually this should work, but it has moved me to my particular follow up question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202978/spark-and-python-trying-to-parse-wikipedia-using-gensim

Comment: @ziky90 "my JSON might be bigger than RAM memory across all the machines" That should not be an issue. If you have one JSON object per line in your source data set, Spark will be able to handle it fine, even if the dataset is huge. Even if you try to cache the dataset, Spark will just cache as much as it can and process the rest from disk.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create an RDD from a python variable using `SparkContext.parallelize()`:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
distData = sc.parallelize(data)
distData.count()   # 5
```

This variable can also be an iterator.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work when the generator generates list bigger than RAM memory, because Spark internally converts generator to list.
Do you have any idea for some workaround here?

Comment: I was afraid that was going to be the case. Sorry I wouldn't know how to proceed further other than doing all your processing within Spark or trying to patch the source code.